# Recreating service vs stopForeground(true)

Tags: android, android-service

I unbind my service when user closes MainActivity. In that case service' onDestroy is called. So I shall not continue using it.

In this case, what do you think about the following idea?

Can't I just call stopForeground(true) on the service? As it is not doing any important thing,  it will just take a little RAM. Afterwards, when user reopens MainActivity (to make something that will require the service), i can re-call startForeground(). Isn't this a good idea? If not, why?

Other possibility is just nulling previous variable which was holding the service (which's onDestroy was called). Afterwards, recreate the service completely.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

> As it is not doing any important thing

Then it does not need to exist, so please allow it to be destroyed after unbinding.

> it will just take a little RAM

What *you* think is "a little" and what the *user* thinks is "a little" may not be the same. Also, it will put an icon in the status bar. In addition, it will cause your process to run with foreground priority, possibly affecting the user's use of the "real" foreground app.

> Isn't this a good idea?

No, it is not a good idea.

> If not, why?

Besides annoying the user, it does not solve any problems.

If the service was holding onto some sort of data, you need to save that data in a persistent store, such as a file or database. Your process can be terminated, by the user or by the OS, at any point, regardless of whether or not you have a service running.

> Other possibility is just nulling previous variable which was holding the service (which's onDestroy was called).

There should not be a "previous variable which was holding the service". There is no need to hold a `Service` in any sort of "variable". And, since my guess is that what you are talking about is what Java programmers refer to as a "static data member", you *definitely* do not want to hold a transient `Context` like a `Service* in a static data member, as that represents a memory leak.

Comment: Shouldn't I  assign the service to some variable so I can send commands to it? Currently I am doing this in `public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)` with `mService = ((MyService.LocalBinder) service).getService();`

Comment: @frankish: First, that's not the service, that's the binder. Second, yes, you should hold onto it, someplace where it can be successfully garbage collected when you are done with the `ServiceConnection`. Usually, your activity (or fragment) holds onto the `ServiceConnection` and its associated binder for that particular component's bound connection to the service.

Comment: I assign it on the main application object. (appcontext) because it is related to a music player so it does not directly connected to any activity. I unbind from the service when nothing is playing which calls onDestroy of service but it doesn't get destroyed (probably because of that assignment in the main application object. so I think I have to set mainAppObject.mService=null in onDestroy method of the service. Afterwards, I have to start over and create a new service.. as far as I understand from your replies. Right?

Comment: @frankish: "I assign it on the main application object. (appcontext) because it is related to a music player so it does not directly connected to any activity" -- IMHO, you are better served using the command pattern, with `startService()` and `stopService()`, for a music player. "which calls onDestroy of service but it doesn't get destroyed" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly?

Comment: If i don't use startForeground, music may stutter on some devices (even the documentation gives "music player" as an example where startForeground may be useful). That is why I use bind/unbind and startForeground. I can say that my service is not destroyed (even onDestroy was called), because after a while when I try to run a command on service, the same object returns successfully without any crash/exceptions. (That is why I hope setting binding variable to null lets gc do it's job :|)